# Configure Django with MS SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql-server, django, sql-server-2012

I'm setting up a `Django` application and I want to use `SQL Server 2012` for my database.

To configure my website I'm following [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/install/#database-installation) section of the official Django documentation.

In the section `Database setup` I found instructions for changing `RDBMS`.

And in `settings.py` file I found these instructions for setting up Django with `SQlite`.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

How I can change this configuration to use `SQL Server 2012` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you'll need django-mssql which requires django 1.4 or below:

http://django-mssql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

It has a pip package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mssql

Then include in your settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'my_database',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': 'dbserver\\ss2008',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: how i can use django-mssql 1.4rc2 for connect to sql server?

Comment: [Here's a version](https://bitbucket.org/Manfre/django-mssql/src) which supports both SQL Server 2012 and Django 1.5. I have used it in the past and can assure that it is working fine, though you need pywin32 build 217 or newer

Comment: for the 2020 readers who ended up here like me and i would highly recommend looking at https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/ got this working with my webapp in 15 mins with a brand new s0 azure sql db.