# why python manage.py sql polls has error?

Tags: python, sql, django, sql-server-2012

I use django .

I create in this file `models.py` my model like this :

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And I change this file `settings.py` like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
)
```

And I change mu database on `SQL Server 2012`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'DjangoFirst',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': 'PCClient',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'sa',
    }
}
```

When I execute this command in `Command prompt`

```
python manage.py sql polls
```

I get this error :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sqlserver_ado' isn't an available
database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named sqlserver_ado.base
```

What is(are) wrong ?

Comment: Don't think django supports _SQL Server 2012_ yet.

Comment: You did not get an answer that helps you?

Comment: not yet?your answer is about postgresql, but i want connect to sql server. and i found my answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265854/how-i-can-configure-django-database-on-sql-server

Comment: @Rohan Any news on when it might be supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

I most use from an another version of `Django` that support `SQL Server 2012` 
and load that in my Python.

I think `django-mssql 1.4rc2` is a good for my purpose.

This is ["Python: Package Index > django-mssql"](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mssql) of version of `Django` that support `SQL Server 2005` and later.

However , I can not use `Django 1.6` and connect to `SQL Server 2012` yet.

Comment: The next version of django-mssql will support Django 1.6 and Django 1.7. https://bitbucket.org/Manfre/django-mssql/

Answer (score 1):

You should to select needed backend module (see all availible modules in comment line). Correct this line:

```
ENGINE = 'postgresql_psycopg2' # 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'
```

Comment: I want use SQL Server 2012 for my database?!?

Comment: Maybe to try this version of [mssql backend](https://bitbucket.org/Manfre/django-mssql/src)?

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems quite explicit: your default database settings are asking for a django database backend that cannot be found - either it does not exist or is not installed or you don't pass the correct python qualified name to your backend.